# Problem with SDDM Display Manager: no bar in the bottom (taskbar?) and applications menu, nor desktop loaded after a second logout/login done

Tags: login, kde, session, logout, sddm

I have Ubuntu-Studio 23.04, KDE plasma 5.27.4 installed and SDDM as a display manager, the autologin is set and works.
When I do a logout, by clicking on "Close session", the SDDM screen appears, and, if I insert the password, the system logins correctly; But if I re-click "close session" and re-insert my password, the system loads only the windows and not the bar at the bottom with the icons (taskbar?), and not even the applications menu, nor the desktop; Furthermore, if I do a third logout/login, the system loads correctly.

When I re-do the logout and login and the system doesn't loads the above things, the following message of error appears in "Settings", "start and shutdown", "background services": "The service manager in the background (Keded5) is not currently being executed and is not currently running . Make sure it is installed correctly. "
I seem to remember, among the many research on the search engines I did (Duckduckgo first of all and then also Google), that in a discussion someone asked, to the user in difficulty, if he had deactivated the Swap partition; And I seem to remember (yes, I have a short memory, and I did the last Ubuntu setup in the Paleolithic) that I did not activate it because I read that having so much RAM (in my case 16 GB) it was a useless thing.

Update: I tried to select gdm3 and lightdm too: same issue and same error message: "The service manager in the background (Keded5) is not currently being executed and is not currently running . Make sure it is installed correctly."

How can I solve?

Thank You very much indeed for the help.

Montezuma III°